# C# NetTcpBinding Client bindings from other config file

Tags: c#, wcf, client, config, nettcpbinding

I have a client which is a windows application called Windows.exe. I have a C# class library called ServiceFacade.dll and it has a config file called ServiceFacade.dll.config. In ServiceFacade.dll.config, I have client side bindings like below

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:5000/MyService" 
                binding="netTcpBinding" 
                contract="IMyService"
                name="NetTcpBinding_MyService"/>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

In ServiceFacade.dll, I have code like below to create proxy

```
NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding("NetTcpBinding_MyService");
ChannelFactory<IMyService> chn = new ChannelFactory<IMyService>(binding);
IMyService service = chn.CreateChannel();
```

Windows.exe calls ServiceFacade.dll to make service calls.

But below line is looking for NetTcpBinding_MyService in Windows.exe.config instead of ServiceFacade.dll.config

**How to make below line to see NetTcpBinding_MyService in ServiceFacade.dll.config but not Windows.exe.config ?**

**NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding("NetTcpBinding_MyService");**

Answer (score 1):

You definitely can copy the configuration to the `ServiceFacade.dll.config` from the `Windows.exe.config`. I would rather create a service endpoint manually than to copy the configuration when I call the service by using ChannelFactory.
Client-side.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri("https://vabqia969vm:21011/");
            NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
            binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
            binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
            binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647;
            ChannelFactory<ITestService> factory = new ChannelFactory<ITestService>(binding, new EndpointAddress(uri));
            ITestService service = factory.CreateChannel();
            var result1 = service.GetData(34);
            Console.WriteLine(result1);
        }

    }
    //The service contract is shared between the client-side and the server-side.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITestService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int id);
    }
```

Wish it is useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

I did like below.

I added below in ServiceFacade.dll.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="netTcpBindingConfiguration"
                 closeTimeout="00:10:00"
                 openTimeout="00:10:00"
                 receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
                 sendTimeout="00:10:00"
                  maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                         maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                         maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <client>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:5000/MyService" 
                binding="netTcpBinding" 
                contract="IMyService"
                name="NetTcpBinding_MYService"                
                bindingConfiguration="netTcpBindingConfiguration" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

In ServiceFacade.dll, I have code like below to create proxy

```
string path = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(path);
ConfigurationChannelFactory<IMyService> chn =
    new ConfigurationChannelFactory<IMyService>(
        "NetTcpBinding_MyService",
        config,
        new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:5000/MyService"));
IMyService iMyService = chn.CreateChannel();
```